# how to parse the output using python?

Tags: python, metrics

I have input file as shown below:

```
name: "locations/us-east"
classification_metrics {
  au_prc: 1.0
  base_au_prc: 0.20000000298
  evaluated_examples_count: 5
  confidence_metrics_entry {
    recall: 1.0
    precision: -1.73472347598e-18
    f1_score: -3.46944695195e-18
    recall_at1: 1.0
    precision_at1: 1.0
    f1_score_at1: 1.0
  }
  confidence_metrics_entry {
    confidence_threshold: 0.10000000149
    recall: 1.0
    precision: 0.178000003099
    f1_score: 0.302207142115
    recall_at1: 1.0
    precision_at1: 1.0
    f1_score_at1: 1.0
  }
  confusion_matrix {
    row {
      example_count: 1
      example_count: 0
      example_count: 0
      example_count: 0
      example_count: 0
    }
    row {
      example_count: 0
      example_count: 1
      example_count: 0
      example_count: 0
      example_count: 0
    }
  }
}
create_time {
  seconds: 1526971489
  nanos: 307150000
}

name: "locations/us-east"
annotation_spec_id: "locations/us-central1"
classification_metrics {
  au_prc: 1.0
  base_au_prc: 0.20000000298
  confidence_metrics_entry {
    recall: 1.0
  }
  confidence_metrics_entry {
    confidence_threshold: 0.00999999977648
    recall: 1.0
    precision: 0.0143612474203
    f1_score: 0.0283158440143
  }
  confidence_metrics_entry {
    confidence_threshold: 0.019999999553
    recall: 1.0
    precision: 0.0287224948406
    f1_score: 0.0558410957456
  }
  confidence_metrics_entry {
    confidence_threshold: 0.0299999993294
    recall: 1.0
    precision: 0.0430837422609
    f1_score: 0.0826084092259
  }
}
create_time {
  seconds: 1526971489
  nanos: 218070000
}
```

I want to parse the input and save it in csv format as `name,annotation_spec_id,classitication_metrics(au_prc,base_au_prc)` and `confidence_metrics_entry(recall,precision,f1)`.

I have tried with `json_loads` and `json_dumps` but it throws different error as No JSON object could be decoded. because this input is not valid json.

how to load and parse the file? with which format should i save the input file?

thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the type of this input file?

Comment: i tried with .txt and as well .json. keep the input in json gives error as it is not valid json format. no idea how to read and parse it as .txt file

Comment: should i convert into json and parse it? or can i parse directly from text file?